# Showing relevant categories on custom taxonomy template

Tags: custom-taxonomy, multi-taxonomy-query

I an using two taxonomies with private posts.

1. category e.g. massage, travel
2. location e.g. new-york-city, boston etc.

On a location page, I want to show categories that are relevant to that location. e.g. If I am on `?location=boston` page I would find all the posts that are in `boston`, then I would find a list of categories in which these posts are categorized. I want this list to be displayed on top of location page.

Is there is a simple, built-in way to do all this?

Comment: You mean, when you're on Boston page, you want to get massage or travel, whatever is available in Boston?

Comment: Yes. e.g. if boston has on 'massage' deals, it should show only 'massage' category. If it has 'travel' deals too then it should show 'travel' category too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `the_loop`, just add this code...

```
<?php
    $cats = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_id(), 'category');
?>
```

Print_r `$cats`, it will have the list of the `categories` applied to this post.